# Acessing the limit values of value_counts(bins)

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to access the limit values when using bins with ***value_counts()***.
For example from:

'(105.004, 133.322]    75'
'(48.368, 76.686]      74'\

to extract the values 105.004 & 133.332 and so on...

Comment: your question is not clear , provide a reproducible sample code/data

Comment: In what context? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
out = df['col'].value_counts(bins=2)
values = [(vals.left, vals.right) for vals in out.index.to_numpy()]
print(values)
print(out)

# Output
[(1.997, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0)]

(1.997, 3.0]    4
(3.0, 4.0]      1
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [2, 4, 2, 3, 3]})
print(df)

# Output
   col
0    2
1    4
2    2
3    3
4    3
```

Comment: Exactly what I've needed.
Thank you :)